# Django cms content getting published in draft mode

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I have installed djangocms-snippet and using placeholder in my template as shown in image[image]

I have included placeholder on template page like

```
{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "Articles" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Issue: whenever I am updating snippet for e.g. news and changing content and then saving its getting reflected automatically in live version without having clicked "publish page changes".Ideally it should only be reflected to the logged in user and after verifying changes are correct I can publish but as soon as i am changing content and saving its getting reflected on live page.Live refers to staging environment here.

Comment: not really familiar with djangocms but if you wanna add an option to publish in draft ,you can add a booleanfield to call draft in your model  and  edit modelmanager  or use filter in your view.

Answer (score 0):

the djangocms-snippet plugin links to existing snippets via a foreignkey field. Those snippets live outside of the plugin on a separate model. If you want to have live/draft for the snippet content, you can just create a plugin which also hosts the content instead of a relationship to the content.

Like so:

```
class SnippetPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    """
    A snippet of HTML or a Django template
    """
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Name'),
        unique=True,
        max_length=255,
    )
    html = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('HTML'),
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```